# AIR Starling viewPort StageText blank

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I have:

```
private var txtField:StageText = new StageText();
txtField.stage = Starling.current.NativeStage;
txtField.viewPort = new Rectangle(200, 150, 400, 35);
```

working however when it's added to the stage you can't see anything. Do I need to apply a background color or...

Thanks.

Comment: yeah you actually shouldn't see anything according to this article on it, if there's no text in there it doesn't have a border by default http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/09/native-text-input-with-stagetext.html

Comment: Yeah I can type in it but can't see an actual input box.

Comment: Yup believe that's normal probably should check out the code he provided there on GitHub as a wrapper to make it a bit easier to use as a normal display object, otherwise sounds like it punches a hole in AIR much the same way a plugin punches a hole in the browser to draw things, so it's dissociated from the normal display tree, says his code simplifies that and I believe adds the border.

Comment: So according to the example (correct me if I am wrong), I just need to add a sprite of some sort at the same position as the StageText and this acts as the background color/image etc. Oh and thanks for the link to the reference.

Comment: I believe so, sorry just dipping my toes into the Starling/Mobile dev business too so I'm not too good for answers in this arena yet, but yeah I believe that's the idea, this just causes problems if you want to put the text input within a scrolling region due to the fact that the Sprite can change position based on it's parent but you have to manually update the position of the StageText viewport.

Comment: I don't think I will have that issue and thanks again for your assistance.